# Can PostGIS Library used without Postgres?

Tags: hadoop, postgis

Is it possible to use PostGIS Library without Postgres? I wanted to use these geospatial functions with Hadoop (MR , HBase , Hive).

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS provides a [`liblwgeom` library](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/postgis-doxygen/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h.html), which is a light-weight geometry library, and is independent of PostgreSQL. [SpatiaLite uses this library for spatial functions with SQLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=liblwgeom-4.0).

`liblwgeom` can be compiled separately using [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48495/how-to-compile-liblwgeom-independently).

Answer (score 1):

Most of PostGIS functions are implemented using [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library. You can use it directly. GEOS is a C++ port of the [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). Possibly in Java will be easier to use it.